# emacs lisp regular expression to detect C++ templates

Tags: regex, lisp

I'm trying to get out of a C++ template expression, stored into property-type, each single type of class, therefore from the type

`A< B < C < D > > >

I want to extract the single types A, B, C, D and place them into a list.`
I wrote the following piece of code in lisp:

```
(if (string-match "\\(\\w+\\)<+\\(\\w+\\)>+$" property-type)
    (progn
      (setq current-include (match-string 1 property-type) )
      (setq current-recursive-property-type (match-string 2 property-type))
```

However the match is wrong, since the first match (current-include) is C and the remainder is D. What is the error in the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions by definition cannot parse arbitrary deep nested groups, so that task is not really possible with regexps in general, however, in this particular case you could pretend that you are splitting the string on a characters `?\<` and `?\>` while removing the empty sub-strings:

```
(split-string "A< B < C < D > > >" "\\s-*[,<>]+\\s-*" t)
```

Would seem to do what you want.

Also note that if you are going to match against a large body of text, and you would have to make it a multiline expression, it is very likely to be very inefficient. So you could use something like this instead:

```
(defun parse-c++-types (type)
  (let ((current 0) c types word)
    (while (< current (length type))
      (setq c (aref type current))
      (if (or (char-equal c ?\<) (char-equal c ?\>))
          (when word
            (setq types (cons (coerce word 'string) types)
                  word nil))
        (unless (memberp c '(?\, ?\ ))
          (setq word (cons c word))))
      (incf current))
    (reverse types)))

(parse-c++-types "A< B < C < D > > >")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be correct to assume that every class name is preceeded by a `<`? If so you can easily match (unescaped)

```
(\w+)(?:\s*<\s*(\w+))*
```

to extract any single class name.

- `(\w+)` is the first class
- `(?:` is a non capturing group

  - `\s*<\s*` spaces before and after the `<`
  - (\w+)
  - `)*` the group is repeated zero or more times

[Here](http://www.rubular.com/r/kV8hONxwla) an example using named groups to show how it works, the *second* group is a multiple match with the last one being D.